# Likert scale and statistical analysis for hypothesis testing

Tags: spss, likert

I am trying to test a hypothesis that the quality of photographic images of big cats will reduce the ability of humans to identify one individual from another based on fur markings.

To test the accuracy, I graded photos by quality using a 1-5 scale. These were used to create a survey, there are 10 questions asking participants to look at the 2 images and state how much they agree with a statement saying the leopards are the same individual. They were asked to decide whether they strongly agree, agree, unsure, disagree or strongly disagree with the statement. The same question is asked for each statement but whether the answer is right or wrong is based on their decision. For example, some are of the same individual and some are not. If they state agree to them both being the same when they are not, then the answer is incorrect.

I have seen a lot of information on using analysis of Likert scale for opinions but not for if the opinion is accurate or not. Hope this makes sense, I am just trying to decide on how to statistically analyze the data to test me hypothesis.